# Привязка события к кнопке WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

При попытке привязать событие к кнопке button1 появляется следующая ошибка. Ругается на эту строчку: 
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click_1);
метод '''private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)''' объявлен в отдельном классе. подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно привязать событие.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == listBox1.Items.Count - 1)

        {

            Record record = new Record();

            record.Name =textBox1.Text;

            record.Fam = textBox2.Text;

            record.Phone = textBox3.Text;

            records.Add(record);

        }

        SaveToFile();

        FillListBox();

    }
```

Comment: "Ругается на эту строчку" - какими словами?

Comment: ошибка cs1061 "form1" не содержит определения "button2_click", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "button2_click", принимающий тип "form1" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)

Comment: у вас метод называется `button1_Click_1`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class OtdelnyjKlass {
  ...
  public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  }
}

OtdelnyjKlass ok = new OtdelnyjKlass();
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(ok.button1_Click_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вы байндите событие на button1 другой формы.

this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click_1);

надо поосторожнее тут. Если объект не будет создан то у вас будут ошибки. Желательно создайте отдельный обработчик в вызываемой форме и тот в свою очередь через dependansy injection будет проверять и вызывать.

```
form1 = new Form1(); 

from2 = new Form2();
from2.Form1 = form1;
from2.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);

public void form2.button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (this.Form1 != null) {
    this.Form1.button1_Click_1(sender, e);
  }
}
```